# Configuring NGINX with proxy_pass set up on a subdirectory pointing to a docker server, and ensuring relative URLs (.js, .css) resolve

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have nginx `1.14.0` running on Ubuntu 18.04 server. On that server, I'm attempting to self-host many different applications. My goal is to have each location exist at a subdirectory of my url, server.calebjay.com.

For example, right now I'd like to set up [pigallery2](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/master/docker/README.md) to be available at `server.calebjay.com/photos`. To do so, I have a docker instance serving on port 800, and I have `nginx` proxying to it. This partially works, insomuch as `index.html` loads.

However, relative urls, such as `script src`, aren't resolving, I believe because they're formed like `main.js` instead of `/photos/main.js`.

To test, I can `GET` https://server.calebjay.com/photos, and resolve an `index.html`. I get 404s for a lot of .js and .css files. Confirming, if I grab those relative URLs, and do `https://server.calebjay.com/photos/main-asdfasdf.js`, I still get a 404, `{server-ip-address}/photos/main-asdf.js` and `https://server.calebjay.com/photos/main-asdf.js` both properly return the given JS file.

There are many answers regarding this, however none have worked for me.

My baseline nginx config:

*/etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

For the subdomain and single docker server to which I'm proxying for now:

*/etc/nginx/sites-available/server.calebjay.com.conf*

```
   server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name server.calebjay.com www.server.calebjay.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    server_name server.calebjay.com; 

    gzip on;


#location ~ \.css {
#    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
#}
#location ~ \.js {
#    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
#}

#location / {
 # if ($http_referer ~ "^https?://[^/]+/photos/") {
 #     rewrite ^/(.*) https://$http_host/photos/$1 redirect;
 # }
#    if ($http_referer = "https://server.calebjay.com/photos/") {
#        rewrite ^/(.*) https://server.calebjay.com/photos/$1 redirect;
#    }
#}

   location /photos/ {
    # rewrite ^/photos(/.*)$ $1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:800/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     # sub_filter "<head>" "<head><base href=\"${scheme}://${host}/photos\">";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.calebjay.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.calebjay.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  }
```

Each of the commented out portions are separate experiments I've tried from various places on the stack network:

[Neither](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064040/2590119) `rewrite` based on `http-referrer` worked, though one image did resolve as a result.

[Having an explicit rule for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671252/production-laravel-returning-404-requests-css-js/61691323#61691323) nor [adding a mime-type header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29574290/2590119) worked.

[Answers regarding static content](https://serverfault.com/questions/937926/how-to-configure-nginx-to-find-subfolders-for-js-css-related-to-index-html) and try_files didn't work, nor should they I believe, as I'm proxying to a server.

[Replacing links using sub_filter](https://serverfault.com/questions/796930/nginx-is-giving-404-errors-on-all-but-the-html-pages/797006#797006) didn't work.

[Setting](https://serverfault.com/a/797253/809575) `location` as `/photos` instead of `/photos/` didn't work.

I don't have access to the docker internals, so can't modify the html directly.

**How can I get my `hrefs` to resolve against the proper domain, with the subdirectory of `/photos/`?**

(I did restart nginx after every config change)

Further details:

*nginx -V*

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-H4cN7P/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

EDIT: Ah, it appears that the `http_referer` `rewrite` solution works in loading js, css, etc, but then the JS application changes the client URL on the client-side, without issuing a request, to `server.calebjay.com/`, thus causing my browser to show `server.calebjay.com/login`, thus causing future requests to miss the `http_referer`. It may be impossible to fix this, as I'm not aware of any way to force javascript to rewrite URLs based on a subdirectory. I may be forced to simply have all my applications on separate subdomains, unless the given application happens to take a subdirectory config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your application's base URL properly, so that it creates proper URLs that match your setup.